# Which is the best http client library based on either C or C++ in terms of performance during heavy parallel downloads?

Tags: linux, open-source, c++, c

Which is the best http client library based on either C or C++ in terms of performance during heavy parallel downloads?

Currently I am looking for developing an C++ application using HTTP client library (for Linux platform preferably). This library should be able to give its best performance even when **CPU is heavily loaded** when **multiple** such **downloads** are happening in **parallel** (say **~35000 downloads**)

Currently I have one option - **libcurl**.

But I have no idea how well does it perform during such scenario described above.

I have been investigating to check if there is any other open source http client library which could help. I came across one link which lists alternatives to libcurl:
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html

Since there are lot of options and I had to discard few based on few criteria like incompatible language, platform, etc. Though I tried using **neon** library at a very basic level.

Still I am not sure which could be the best option.

Kindly suggest me which could be the better option with high latency which could serve the requirement I am looking for. You could also share your thoughts of any of you have benchmarked libcurl against other http client libraries with the scenario described above.

Please do let me know if any details are required.
Looking forward for reply. Thank you.

Comment: Other competitors to libcurl are listed here: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html One that is not listed there is c++-netlib http://cpp-netlib.org/# Hope you find the library you prefer above. I am going with libcurl myself to start with.

Comment: @JacWright Are you going to use libcurl with 35000 parallel downloads? If yes post an answer with your feedback/measures, thanks! :-)